# File.Exists not working on network, even if app is ran as administrator

Tags: file, networking, .net-4.5, exists

I tried checking file existence on network while running app as administrator, using this code:

```
// file exists at : \\net0\shared\1.txt
var networkPath=@"\\net0\shared\1.txt";
var ex=File.Exists(networkPath);
```

But **ex** is false.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Create a FileInfo instance and check if that exists:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"\\net0\shared\1.txt");
var exists = fi.Exists;
```

Comment: FileInfo has same problem!

Comment: Are you using a domain admin account to run the app?